# set visibility of button when input is provided in edit text

Tags: android

I have one button 'OK'. One edit text.
I want to make the 'OK' button visible only when we provide input in edit text.
As soon as I type first number in edit text, button should be visible.

How do I code this in android studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example. You'll need to intialize the variables yourself, which can be easily learned by Googling.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        button.setVisibility(s.length > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
});
```

Comment: Do i need to make changes in XML file, cause it isn't getting invisible. Its visible since the first second of me launching the app.

Comment: You'll need to put `android:visibility="invisible"` in the Button's XML so that's it's invisible by default.

Comment: Can you help me with animation? I want to place animation of celebration(ribbons all over the screen) when user wins. I had posted this question yesterday.

Comment: Animations are not my thing, but I can tell you that you'll need a GIF (unless you're going to be making your own graphics in a View somehow) and some View that can play that GIF, such as a WebView.

Comment: Okay.. i'll see. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically in the code below, i have added **TextChangeListener** to edittext which listens when anything is written in edittext and **setVisibility** attribute helps to switch the visibility of button.

```
   editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

       if(s.toString().trim().length()==0){
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          } else {
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: It isn't getting invisible.

Comment: put android:visibility="invisible" in the Button's XML

Comment: Up-voted. But my reputation isn't more than 15 yet.. so my upvote isn't visible. Sorry.. its my 3rd day here.

Answer (score -1):

```
**Try below code. I hope it will help you.**

editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      if(s.length() != 0)
     button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

   }
  });
```

Comment: Done. Thank-you. :)

Comment: Can you help me with animation in android?

Comment: Simple animation.. if user wins the game.. 'USER WINS' is displayed.. and ribbons all over the screen.. like celebration animation if user wins.